# Making table rows using for loop

Tags: java, android, list, for-loop

I'm trying to make table rows using for-loop and setting the text from a list but it repeats the list from the beginning and not displaying the next batch of list elements.

Creating row header

```
String[] tableHeader = {"Session ID", "Date & Time", "Syllabary", "Mistakes", "Score", "Time", "Wrong Characters", "User ID"};
TableRow rowHead = new TableRow(this);
for (String text : tableHeader) {
    TextView columns = new TextView(this);
    columns.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    columns.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    columns.setTextSize(18);
    columns.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    columns.setText(text);

    rowHead.addView(columns);
}
tableLayout.addView(rowHead);
```

sessionList contains:

```
[5, 12/10/2022 12:04:08 AM, 10 chars hira, 5, 5, 00m:05s, [ら, た, ら, ら, は], 1, 
4, 12/09/2022 10:10:36 PM, 10 chars hira, 5, 5, 00m:04s, [わ, な, あ, な, あ], 1, 
2, 12/09/2022 07:39:14 PM, 10 chars kata, 7, 3, 00m:05s, [ハ, ラ, ア, マ, ハ, マ, ヤ], 1]
```

Creating rows

```
for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < allSession.size(); rowCount++) { // creates 3 rows
      TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

      for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount < sessionList.size(); columnCount++) {
            TextView columns = new TextView(this);
            columns.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            columns.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            columns.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            columns.setTextSize(18);
            columns.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            columns.setText(sessionList.get(columnCount)); // always starts at the beginning

            row.addView(columns);
      }
      tableLayout.addView(row);

}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ5BQ.png)

Comment: Please be specific in your explanation of your problem, including examples of what you expect to receive and the problem you encounter.

Comment: @OrkhanGG my bad, here is a picture of the table rows I expected to be [link](https://imgur.com/a/hZZ8n6K)